# Reasoning about `parMap`

Tags: haskell

Given:

```
Prelude Control.Parallel.Strategies> :t parMap
parMap :: Strategy b -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

Prelude Control.Parallel.Strategies> :i Strategy
type Strategy a = a -> Eval a
        -- Defined in `Control.Parallel.Strategies'
```

My understanding then is that `parMap` can be expanded, replacing `b` with `b -> Eval b` to:

`parMap :: (a -> b -> Eval b) -> (a -> b -> Eval b) -> [b -> Eval b]`

This seems more complicated than the example version in [Parallel and Concurrent Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-sudoku2):

```
parMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Eval [b]
parMap f [] = return []
parMap f (a:as) = do
   b <- rpar (f a)
   bs <- parMap f as
   return (b:bs)
```

In the standard library implementation of `parMap`, what's the meaning of `Strategy b`, namely in `a -> b -> Eval b`?

Comment: In your expansion of `parMap`, you forgot the last `[a]` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in your interpretation, `Strategy` is not a type class but a type alias. If you check the signature of `parMap`, `Strategy b` is followed by `->` and not by `=>` which means that `parMap` expects a `Strategy b` as first argument. `Strategy b` is alias for `b -> Eval b` which means that the signature of `parMap` can be expanded to:

```
parMap :: (b -> Eval b) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The book `parMap` is not the same as the one above because its signature is

```
parMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> Eval [b]
```

The main difference is that the first version uses the given `Strategy b` to compute a `[b]` from the arguments `(a -> b) -> [a]` while the second version doesn't compute a `[b]` but a `Eval [b]`. `Eval [b]` specifies how to produce a `[b]` and you must call `runEval` to use it.

The first version is easier to use in a program because you don't need to call `runEval` and it's also better because the strategy to evaluate each element of the list is not predefined, like in the book where the strategy is `rpar`, but it's an argument. This means that the first version is more generic. Have a look at the [basic strategies](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:r0) to better understand what you can pass to the standard `parMap`.